# WIN32 C Properly using SetWindowLongPtr and GetWindowLongPtr

Tags: c, winapi

Yes this is a homework assignment and I'm completely stumped.

So I've made a struct and two windows:

```
typedef struct thingy {
int count;
TCHAR* MSG;
COLORREF colour; };
```

The windows have:

```
wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wndclass.cbClsExtra = sizeof(thingy*);
wndclass.cbWndExtra = sizeof(thingy*);
```

I need one window to display 0 and the next to display 1 using this struct stored in the clsextra using SetWindowLongPtr and GetWindowLongPtr/SetClassLongPtr and GetClassLongPtr

Count of course has to be initialized to 0 for the FIRST window but not for the second and I have no idea how to do this. Only one WndProc can be used to do this.

```
static thingy* mythingy = (thingy*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, 0);
char buf[128];
int num = GetClassLongPtr(hwnd, 0);
static boolean set = false;

    case WM_CREATE:
    if (!set) {
        mythingy = (thingy*)malloc(sizeof(thingy));
        mythingy->count = 0;
        mythingy->colour = RGB(0, 0, 0);
        mythingy->MSG = TEXT("Hello Windows!");
        set = true;
    }
    if (lParam != NULL) {
        SetClassLongPtr(hwnd, 0, (LONG)mythingy->count);
    }
    mythingy->count++;
    SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, 0, (LONG)mythingy);
    return 0;

case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

    DrawText(hdc, mythingy->MSG, -1, &rect,
        DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

    sprintf_s(buf, "%d", num);
    TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, LPCWSTR(buf), 1);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
```

Right now both windows display 1 and I'm struggling to see why it isn't doing what I want as I can't find anything on Google about how to use these two functions or when I need to be calling them.

Window: 0x000a0528
count = 0
Add to class data

Window: 0x001f099a
count = 1
Add to class data

From the paint method I get the data and both of them are 1.

Comment: Why are you manipulating the class long pointers? Are you trying to keep a count of how many windows you're making? And `lParam` will never be NULL in `WM_CREATE`; it will always be a pointer to that window's `CREATESTRUCT` structure.

Comment: Yes, the assignment says "in wm_paint, display the count from clsextra" count is supposed to correspond to how many windows are being made. I noticed from the debugger that lParam would probably never be NULL but the assignment says "in wm_create you need to check if the lParam is NULL" so I'm just doing what it says.

Screenshot of example given: http://puu.sh/keaAF/cc6dc62bbc.png

Comment: Both windows are of the same class, so accessing data in the *cbClsExtra* memory, accesses the same shared data. When the second window is created, you're writing `1` to the *cbClsExtra* memory, and access that in your `WM_PAINT` handler. If you want to access window-private data, you'll have to access the data stored in the *cbWndExtra* memory instead. In short: Store the total count of windows in the *cbClsExtra* memory, and store each window's index in the *cbWndExtra* memory.

Comment: If the assignment _requires_ the use of the _class_ memory space, which is _not_ the right way to associate something with a specific window, then a potential option would be to store the window handle and number in a struct, put an array of those structs into the class space, which you could then iterate through inside the `WM_PAINT` handler to determine the correct number for the HWND being painted. (If that's not clear, I can flesh it out into an actual answer.) Also, a side note: While this _is_ homework, you've asked a _specific_ question about a _specific_ problem, so it is perfectly ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Window Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632596.aspx)

> ... is a set of attributes that the system uses as a template to create a window. Every window is a member of a window class.

Since the Windows API is exposed as a flat C interface, there is no inheritance at the language level. The phrase *"is a member of"* is implemented by sharing the class memory across window instances of that class. Consequently, every call to [GetClassLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633581.aspx) accesses the same shared memory.

In contrast, each window can reserve *cbWndExtra* bytes of memory, that are attributed to the specific window instance. This memory is private to each window, and can store per-window data.

To implement your requirements you need to store the common information (current count of windows) in the window class' extra memory (*cbClsExtra*), and keep the per-window data (index, message, and color) in the window instance's extra memory (*cbWndExtra*).

Apply the following changes to your code:

```
// Total count of windows stored as an integer:
wndclass.cbClsExtra = sizeof(int);
```

In the `WM_CREATE`-handler, set the per-window data, increment the total count, and store it away:

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    int count = (int)GetClassLongPtr(hwnd, 0);
    // Allocate new per-window data object:
    thingy* mythingy = (thingy*)malloc(sizeof(thingy));
    mythingy->count = count;
    mythingy->colour = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    mythingy->MSG = TEXT("Hello Windows!");
    // Store the per-window data:
    SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, 0, (LONG_PTR)mythingy);
    // Increment total count and store it in the class extra memory:
    ++count;
    SetClassLongPtr(hwnd, 0, (LONG_PTR)count);
}
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```

In the `WM_PAINT`-handler, access the per-window data:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
    // Retrieve per-window data:
    thingy* mythingy = (thingy*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, 0);

    DrawText(hdc, mythingy->MSG, -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

    char buf[128];
    sprintf_s(buf, "%d", mythingy->count);
    TextOutA(hdc, 0, 0, buf, 1);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
}
```

*Note: All error handling has been elided for brevity. Character-encoding issues have not really been addressed either (`char` vs. `wchar_t`). Likewise, resource management is missing. You'd probably want to deallocate memory in a `WM_NCDESTROY`-handler. The code assumes, that only windows of a single window class are created.*

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted. I wasn't aware that clsextra was shared although I had my suspicions after it was printing out the same number for both windows.